# Is there a way to reduce garbage collection and/or dynamic dispatch for Julia Flux gradient calls?

Tags: julia, gradient, flux, dynamic-dispatch

Does anyone know if there's any way to reduce the amount of gc and/or dynamic dispatch for a gradient call in flux? I've tried using [FastClosures.jl](https://github.com/c42f/FastClosures.jl), as well as wrapping loss into a callable struct to prevent closures and consequently Core.Box calls, but nothing seems to make an appreciable difference.

MWE:

```
using Flux

function get_grad(dnn, x, y)
    p = params(dnn)
    g = gradient(p) do
        Flux.mse(dnn(x),y)
    end
    return g
end

const DNN = Dense(3, 2)
const X = rand(Float32, 3)
const Y = rand(Float32, 2)

@profiler for _ in 1:10_000; get_grad(DNN, X, Y); end
```

[Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI45A.png) (orange - dynamic dispatch, red - garbage collection, dynamic dispatch)

[Zygote\src\compiler\interface.jl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTTvt.png)